# python add an array to database

Tags: python, mysql, numpy

I'm trying to get arrays from H5 files using h5py and write them into a MySQL database.
I wrote this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys, os, h5py, MySQLdb, numpy

def initial(FileName):
    f = h5py.File(str(FileName), 'r')

    ch1 = f[str("dset1")][:]
    ch2 = f[str("dset2")][:]
    ch3 = f[str("dset3")][:]
    ch4 = f[str("dset4")][:]
    ch5 = f[str("dset5")][:]
    ch6 = f[str("dset6")][:]
    ch7 = f[str("dset7")][:]
    ch8 = f[str("dset8")][:]
    ch9 = f[str("dset9")][:]
    ch10 = f[str("dset10")][:]
    ch11 = f[str("dset11")][:]
    ch12 = f[str("dset12")][:]
    ch13 = f[str("dset13")][:]
    ch14 = f[str("dset14")][:]
    ch15 = f[str("dset15")][:]

    print(numpy.shape(ch1))

    db = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost", user="myUSR", passwd="myPasswd", db = "myDB")
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("INSERT INTO myTable (FileName, date, ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch4r, ch5, ch6, ch7, ch8, ch9, ch10, ch11, ch12, Slot, Info) values ( " +
    "\"" + str(FileName) + "\"" +\
    ",\"" +"Bu aralar" + "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch1 + "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch2 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch3 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch4 + "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch5 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch6 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch7 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch8 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch9 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch10 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch11 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch12 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch13 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch14 +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + ch15 +  "\"" + " ) ")
    db.commit()

initial(sys.argv[1])
```

However there is an error telling that I can't write such a data to database. So I tried to put srt() for each data like this:

```
    .
    .
    .
    ",\"" + str(ch4) + "\"" +\
    ",\"" + str(ch5) +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + str(ch6) +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + str(ch7) +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + str(ch8) +  "\"" +\
    ",\"" + str(ch9) +  "\"" +\
    .
    .
    .
```

But it disrupt my data. This is how my arrays look like in data base

```
[[  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 [  0   0   0 ...,   0   0   0]
 ..., 
 [500 432 472 ...,  46  46  32]
 [309 231 325 ...,  47  47  40]
 [187 236 363 ...,  44  39  39]]
```

So can you please advice me a way to write my arrays to database?

Comment: I could not get what exactly error is but I would suggest use string.format() to avoid mess with quotes
`query = 'insert into table_name (FileName, date, .....) values("{0}","{1}",...)'.format([str(FileName),ch1,....])` then `cur.execute(query)`

Answer (score 1):

Dump your array to `pickle` or `json`. It is better way instead of `str()`.